# If no value before decimal, then add zero (in Python 2.7)

Tags: python

I have the following values:

```
.03
.04
1.23
```

I would like to add 0 to any of the values that do not have a value before the decimal place. So the output would be:

```
0.03
0.04
1.23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming that what you have are strings, in this case, ever the ever so simple

```
print (float(a))
```

works  example

```
print (float(".03"))
```

0.03

Answer (score 0):

if `n` is your number, this should get you what you want

```
'%03.2f' % n
```

If you want other options, see this link https://pyformat.info/#number for plenty of information about formatting numbers and strings in python.

Comment: If n is already a float, the zero will always be present, even without being formatted

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
z = format(.03, 'f')
print z
```